# Regular Expression for Some Value and Some Value

Tags: c#, regex

I want a `Regex` for `Somevalue.......Somevalue`. Like:

```
vikas?notsure233R&amp;kratika
vikas?hopeitwork3&amp;kratika
vikas?wouldItWork&amp;kratika
```

I tried

```
(vikas?[(.*?)]&amp;kratika)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: are you trying to parse url..if so there are api's to help you with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems here.
`?` is a special character inside a regex, you have to escape it.
`[]` makes a character class, so you're trying to match either ***, *.* or *?*

So, all in all:

```
vikas\?(.*?)&amp;kratika
```

Answer (score 3):

it should be `vikas\?(.*?)&amp;kratika`

**Update:**

if you're trying to parse those URLs, you can decode them first by using [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx).

Then use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) to parse the URL:

```
String DecodedUrl = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(YourUrl);
NameValueCollection UrlParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(DecodedUrl);
if (UrlParameters.AllKeys.Contains("SOMETHING")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Because they're the same ;-) consider accepting one of them so the question will be marked as resolved.